# Modify this regex: {([^\]]*)} to accept \]

Tags: php, regex, escaping, pcre

I've got this regex:

```
{([^\]]*)} // any character except ']' but i want it to accept also '\]' this combination of 2chars
```

Example

```
'Lorem Ipsum is simply] dummy text' should return => 'Lorem Ipsum is simply' (and this ones does) but
'Lorem Ipsum is simply\] dummy text' => should return all the text because the ']' is escaped
```

hope it makes sense

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an alternation:

```
(?:\\\]|[^\]])*
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
'~(?:[^\\\\\\]]*|\\\\.)*~' // (?:[^\\\]]|\\.)*
```

Unlike Marks answer this is able to parse `[\\]]` as `\\` which will give you ability to use `\` as universal escape character not just for `\]`.